# DateFormat not giving date in the desired format

Tags: java, date-format

I want to get the current date in the following format 
yyyy_mm_dd

Am Using the below code

```
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_mm_dd");
Date datetoday = new Date();
System.out.println(date.format(datetoday));
```

But its giving the result in this manner - 2013_56_25

However, it should give the result like **2013_03_25**

Infact, the *mm* value varies every time I run it.
My system's date is of the format - 3/25/2013. (Idk if it has some relation with this)

What is the possible problem with this ?

Comment: letters are cases sensitive -  see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use upper case `MM`, lower case `mm`  is for minutes.

```
DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
```

Comment: sorry!! but feeling laughy. :D

Answer (score 7):

Month is M, not m (which is minute)

Answer (score 7):

Use **MM** instead of **mm**; lower case is for mintues; Uppercase for Months

Answer (score 3):

You will have to  use MM and not mm. Please refer the table from the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got Different Result after parse the java.util.Date to java.sql.Date
String date="2012-05-02";

SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

i got as a result is:2012-01-01

means 1 Day is less than actually required.